# Rails3 - changing links into graphic button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to change the standard links and buttons in Rails to a graphic version. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, for standard links, you can do something like:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/images/link.png'), link_path %>
```

For submit buttons, you can use the `image_submit_tag` helper within your form:

```
<%= form_for ... %>
    <%= image_submit_tag '/images/submit.png' %> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given how reduced the graphic version is, why not use CSS? No need to change any of the mark–up or template tags. — http://jsfiddle.net/ry5KD/ (super–reduced example!).